# Formatting date from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, date-format

Below is my function for inserting records to my database through HTML form. However I want my date to be typed in *dd-mm-yyyy* format and then be saved to my database as default *yyyy-mm-dd* format. I tried with strtotime and DateTime::createFromFormat(as you can see these are commented out lines) but nothing works for me.Can I get your help with it?

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function addRecord(){
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
    $this->postVariablesToClassVariables() ;

    //$this->ldate= DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->ldate)->format('Y-m-d');
    //$this->ldate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->ldate));

    if($this->lno && $this->ldate && $this->version && $this->company &&){

    $ins = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `mlicenses_table`(`lno`,`ldate`,`version`,`company`)
    VALUES  ('".$_POST['lno']."','".$_POST['ldate']."','".$_POST['version']."', '".$_POST['company']."')");

    $this->resetClassVariables();
    return $this->errorMessages= "New records added to database" ;

    }
    else {

    $this->errorMessages="Enter all fields required " ;
    return;
    }
    }
```

Comment: `$output = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("-",$input)));`

Comment: Also [obligatory xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/327/) - start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) before it's too late!

Comment: The second one, or `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("11-07-2014"));`, was already correct. Show your debugging output, and explain how it deviated.

Comment: show what you getting in $this->ldate?

Comment: If I enter date in dd-mm-yyyy format database field shows 0000-00-00

Comment: cause you need to send Y-m-d format